# "the system cannot find the file specified" error when working with Notepad++ NppExec

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, batch-file

The above error recently appeared when trying to implement the steps in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44046/90915). To summarize, I'm implementing an automated method to compile pdf files quickly using LaTeX; I call a batch file from within the [NppExec](https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/672146/thread/f829c882/) plugin environment which carries out the process of compiling the pdf file.

I have implemented this script a couple of times before on Windows 7 PCs without issue. This time I tried it on a new Windows 10 PC, and it couldn't find the `pdflatex` executable when running from NppExec, even though it was in my system environment variables, and was successfully found when running on the command line or running the batch file directly, but not when the batch file was run within the NppExec.

How can I resolve this so it works as expected?

Answer (score -1):

The key for me was to add the file paths of the desired programs to the `Path` in the **user environment variables**. I had already set it in the system environment variables, but then I noticed another program I was calling was only located in the user variables.

I highly suspect there have been some changes in how environment variables are loaded in different contexts between Windows 7, 8, and 10, as I had done this setup before in Windows 7 and programs located in the system `Path` environment variable could always be found for me.

Comment: After you set them as system-level variable, did you reboot before attempting to use them?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I restarted Notepad++, but not the system... Do you think this would have resolved the issue?

Comment: Probably, as system variables are loaded at system startup.   That's an untested theory right now tho.. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Hmm... I'll test it out later and amend my answer.